# Images are intermittently distorted when copy-pasted into Power Point

Tags: high-sierra, ms-office

This is just a small addition to an existing topic, but it's driving me crazy and I don't see an answer anywhere, or have time to gain user points. I reluctantly switched to High Sierra recently on my MacBook and MacBook Pro (I have a lot of old software I'm happy with). When pasting images from a browser or pdf (or probably anywhere) into Office 2008 Power Point, they often come out skewed in the way others have shown. Doesn't seem to matter if I use shortcut keys, or Paste, or Paste Special. What will sometimes cure it is closing the Power Point and opening it again, which is obviously not very practical. I can paste into Illustrator, so it seems to be a Power Point issue. Has anybody figured this out?

Thanks,

Barbara

Comment: That is 10 year old software running on (essentially) a brand new operating system. Some people can't even get Office 08 to launch on an OS newer than El Cap, that it even works is a minor miracle.

Answer (score 1):

Bypass the copy/paste directly into PowerPoint procedure and instead, paste the copied image into a new Preview.app document, export the image into a .gif, .png or .jpg formatted file onto your computer, and then import the file into PowerPoint. It takes more steps, but it should work.